# Xlookup with intermediate table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get the values from one table to another table where there is a match. Normally I'd use Xlookup but the catch is that the matches may not be exact. I have a third table where the allowed "synonyms" are detailed.

For example, I want "Steve", to match against "Steve", "Steven", "Steve-O".

So if my source tables look like this:

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amelia | Amy | Ames |  |
| Steven | Steve-O | Steve |  |
| John | Jonathan | Jon | Johnny |

| Count | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Amy |
| 3 | Steven |
| 6 | Johnny |

My result table, where I enter the function, should be

| Count | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Amelia |
| 3 | Steve |
| 6 | John |

Because Amy and Amelia are synonyms according to the Name table, they are a match.

Answer (score 1):

We can use INDEX/AGGREGATE to return the full row and use SUMIFS to return the number:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(F:F,G:G,INDEX(A:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$D$4)/($A$2:$D$4=J1),1),0)))
```

[image]

One note if the name is used more than once in the range in F:G it will return the sum and not the first encountered.  So if you had `Ames` in G4 and `5` in F4, `Amelia` would return `15`

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using dynamic array functionality:

[image]

Formula in `C7`:

```
=MAP(B7:B9,LAMBDA(x,@FILTER(A2:A4,BYROW(A2:D4,LAMBDA(y,SUM(N(y=x)))))))
```